# GWTP implementation of TabContainer for PresenterWidget

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I am using GWTP for an application. In this app, I often need to do a `PresenterWidget` which contains tabs with a `PresenterWidget` in each tab.

As the container is a `PresenterWidget`, I cannot use class `TabContainerPresenter` so I am doing my own implementation.

I encounter some problems while trying to manage the lifecycle of `PresenterWidget` contained in the tabs (`onReveal()`, `onHide()` etc).

**First question** : In this particular case, is it recommended to manually call `onReveal()`, `onHide()` etc?

**2nd question** : I tried to manage lifecycle without calling those methods.

This is what I do : When user clicks on a tab, the main presenter calls `setInSlot(index,presenterWidget)` to put the corresponding `PresenterWidget` in the right tab.

But : When I click on a tab, `onReveal()` is called on the corresponding `PresenterWidget` (good!) then `onReset()` is called on all `PresenterWidget` : why all? I would expect that `onReset()` is called only on the `PresenterWidget` corresponding to the active tab.

=> Is `setInSlot()` the right method to call in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might be of help: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-%22Slots%22

1. I wouldn't recommend to call the lifecycle method manually. It should work just fine without them.
2. You want to use the `setInSlot()` method because at any point only one `PresenterWidget` is active.

However you are using different SLOTS for each `PresenterWidget`. The way `setInSlot()` works is that it replaces whatever `PresenterWidget` that was assigned to that slot. Because you use different slots for each tab, it won't remove the other `PresenterWidgets`. The other `PresenterWidget`s stay in their slots and probably that's the reason why `onReset()` is called on them.
You have 2 choices:

- If you want to keep the different slots you should call `removeFromSlot` on all non-visible `PresenterWidgets`.
- Specify just one slot (TAB_CONTENT) and simply use `setInSlot()`

Comment: I tried the solution with one slot as I display one widget at a time. It works far better but still not perfectly : now, if I click on a tab, `onHide()` is called on the previous tab, `onReveal()` then `onReset()` are called only on the new tab. The problem is that those 2 methods are always both called.I would expect that `onReveal()` was called only when the tab is displayed for the first time. Is it right? Is there anything I can do to have this behavior?

Comment: No `onReveal()` and `onReset` are called together (see https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle). You can use `onBind()` to do things when the `Presenter` is created or you use a flag to know if is it the first time